# OpenCV: Reading a video with multiple cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, video

I am working on a program that does simple analyzation (color, etc) of videos, specifically films. Since films are often thousands of frames long, I figured that it would be inefficient to use simply iterate through the video by using the `cap.read()` function to capture each frame individually. I would like to use multiple cores or processes to read and save the pertinent information from each frame for certain sections of the video; for example, have one core read and analyze frames from the first quarter of the video, while other core do the same for other parts, and combine information after all frames have been read. How might this be done?

I am relatively new to opencv and the practice of multithreading, but I am eager to learn. Even if you are able to provide some resources for me to look at, I would appreciate it a lot!